# Count of combination of columns regardless of order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
from    to  
a       b
b       a
c       d
c       d
d       c
```

I want to find the count of the combination of `from` and `to` regardless of the order so I'll end up with something like:

```
places  count
[a,b]   2
[c,d]   3
```

I'm struggling to find a effective way of achieving this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use value_counts() with the elements in zipped columns with frozenset. This can cause you to get ['d','c']. If you however prefer them sorted you can go and do: `tuple(sorted(i)) for i in zip()` instead of `map(frozenset,...)`. There seem to be a `4x` speed-boost compared to using the groupby-solution. **Update**: The speed comparison is not really fair as the two solutions does different things.

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
from    to  
a       b
b       a
c       d
c       d
d       c'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

out = pd.Series(map(frozenset,zip(df['from'],df['to']))).value_counts().reset_index()
out.rename(columns={'index':'places',0:'count'}, inplace=True)

print(out)
```

And you get:

```
   places  count
0  (d, c)      3
1  (a, b)      2
```

Time comparison:

```
%timeit pd.Series(map(frozenset,zip(df['from'],df['to']))).value_counts()
%timeit df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).groupby(['from','to']).size()

1000 loops, best of 3: 845 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.45 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [41]: df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).groupby(['from','to']).size()
Out[41]:
from  to
a     b     2
c     d     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You can use `np.sort` if you imported numpy as np.  `df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).groupby(['from','to']).size()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter` for an O(n) solution:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(map(frozenset, (zip(df['from'], df['to']))))

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').reset_index()

print(res)

#     index  0
# 0  (a, b)  2
# 1  (c, d)  3
```

Note conversion to `frozenset` is required since `Counter` only works on hashable objects. However, this should be more efficient than a `groupby` solution.

Comment: Yes, but this is a copy of my solution but with Counter instead of value.counts().

Comment: @AntonvBR, Really? I'm not sure `Counter` works *exactly* the same way as `value_counts()` [or does it? I haven't checked the pandas source code]. The `map(frozenset,(...))` of course is the same because both methods require hashable objects.

Comment: Well maybe not internally. But since your solution can be simplified to `pd.Series(Counter(map(frozenset, zip(df['from'], df['to'])))).reset_index()`, comparing it to: `pd.Series(map(frozenset,zip(df['from'],df['to']))).value_counts().reset_index()` is basically the same. My original solution actually had Counter() in it but I thought it would be better to stick with pandas functions for readability. However, running tests there seem to be a speed-boost running Counter().

Comment: @AntonvBR, OK, I see that now. To be honest, I didn't look *that closely* at your solution. I've upvoted yours, looks fine to me.